# How many tablespoons of yogurt should an 11-month-old eat?

Tags: infant, food

Our 11-month-old loves yogurt, and would eat it constantly if we let him.  How much is too much assuming his weight is ok?

Answer (score 9):

How much sugar is in this yogurt? Plain yogurt is fine in high quantities, but sugar rich yogurt is not much better than ice cream. If it's sugar rich, he shouldn’t eat much of it at all, end of story.

If it is plain non sugary yogurt though, the thing to guard against is him eating *only* yogurt. I will offer the following guidelines:

1. Limit yogurt to two meals/snacks a day
2. When offering yogurt, mix something else like fruit or chicken with it. You can use his affinity for yogurt to introduce other foods
3. If he refuses to eat other foods or cries for yogurt, might be time to take a 2-3 day break.

Comment: Welcome to the site! "...the thing to guard against is him eating only yogurt." Perfect! Nice answer, +1

Comment: I am wondering what you mean by"When offering yogurt, mix something else like fruit or chicken with it."
With fruit I simply would have guessed, that you want a bit of fruit in the yogurt, but chicken?
How would you mix yogurt with chicken?

Comment: It’s pretty common in Mediterranean food to have yogurt sauce on meat, think about it like a chicken salad type dish. I wouldn’t make it for myself but a one year old who loves yogurt, definitely.

Comment: @Etaila - Ranch dressing is used here (US) on everything under the sun, though it's meant for salad greens, including chicken wings and pizza. I thought yogurt with chicken was initially strange, but realized user35316 had a good idea here.